# My Back Propagation function is not working in neural network using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

here is my code

```
def mlp_gradients(mlp, loss_function, x, y):
```

"""
Compute the gradient of loss with respect to mlp's weights and biases
Args:
mlp: An object of MLP class
loss_function: A function used as loss function of the MLP
x: A numpy array of shape (batch_size, input_dim). The MLP's input
y: A numpy array of shape (batch_size, num_classes). Target labels

Returns:
gradients: A list of dictionaries {'w': dw, 'b': db} corresponding to the dictionaries in mlp.parameters
dw is the gradient of loss with respect to the weights of the layer
db is the gradient of loss with respect to the bias of the layer

"""

```
 gradients = []
```

#### get the output of the network

```
 y_hat = mlp.activations[-1]
  num_layers = len(mlp.parameters)
```

#### compute gradient of the loss with respect to network output

```
 g = loss_function(y, y_hat, return_grad=True)
```

#### You'll need the input in the last step of backprop so let's make a new list with x in the beginning

```
 activations = [x] + mlp.activations 




for i in reversed(range(num_layers)):
    ########################################
    #     Put your implementation here     #
    l2_error=loss_function(y,y_hat,return_grad=False)
    if mlp.act_funcs[-1]==relu:
      deriv_variable=relu(y_hat,True)
      l2_delta=l2_error*deriv_variable
    elif mlp.act_funcs[-1]==sigmoid:
      deriv_variable=sigmoid(y_hat,True)
      l2_delta=l2_error*deriv_variable
    else:
      deriv_variable=linear(y_hat,True)
      l2_delta=l2_error*deriv_variable 
    l1_error=l2_delta.dot(mlp.weighted_ins[-1].T)
    if mlp.act_funcs[-2]==relu:
        deriv_variable=relu(y_hat,True)
        l1_delta=l1_error*deriv_variable
    elif mlp.act_funcs[-1]==sigmoid:
        deriv_variable=sigmoid(y_hat,True)
        l1_delta=l1_error*deriv_variable
    else:
        deriv_variable=linear(y_hat,True)
        l1_delta=l1_error*deriv_variable
    Layer1=x.T.dot(l1_delta)
    Layer2=l1_error.T.dot(l2_delta)
    ########################################
    gradients.append(Layer1)
    gradients.append(Layer2)
    
  return gradients
```

but its not working...
i use numpy for backpropagation and google colab